# Oracle large single update or small batch updates?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to update a table that contains several millions of rows. The update is pretty straightforward but as it will modify millions of records I wonder what is the best solution:

- Perform one big update.
- Update the table and commit the changes in small batches using bulk collect/forall statements.

I would go for the first solution but a colleague suggests me to do it in batches so it would not block other sessions accessing the table.

So which solution is the better ?

Thanks,

Comment: [Tom Kyte's comment on frequent commits](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022): "*is wrong, wrong, wrong. So wrong.... So very very wrong*" or "*Frequently commiting ... does this for you: slows you down, yes, that is right, SLOWS YOU DOWN*"

Comment: Makes sense, I now have good arguments to stick with my solution. Thanks.

Comment: IIRC some huge updates have issues with rollback segments ("ORA-01555: snapshot too old"), which is why it is sometimes recommended to update blockwise.

Answer (score 2):

If your db has downtime, the fastest solution is probably to do as [Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330) says:

```
create table new as select ... from old;
drop table old;
rename table new to old;
```

If you don't have a window where this can happen (it is probably orders of magnitude faster) and blocking the table isn't allowed then I recommend you check out dbms_parallel_execute.  Oracle can split the table into chunks and update each chunk separately. It's much cleaner than bulk collecting and updating forall because you can just use the update statement you would have if you wanted one big update with the added condition `and rowid between :start and :stop`

```
begin
  dbms_parallel_execute.create_task ( task_name => 'MyTask');
  dbms_parallel_execute.create_chunks_by_rowid(
      task_name   => 'MyTask',
      table_owner => 'Me',
      table_name  => 'MyTable',
      by_row      => true,
      chunk_size  => 1000);
  dbms_parallel_execute.run_task(
      task_name      => 'MyTask',
      sql_stmt       => 'UPDATE mytable
                            set col = newval
                          where ...
                            and rowid between :start_id and :end_id',
      language_flag  => dbms_sql.native,
      parallel_level => 8);
```

then, once it's done you check the status:

```
dbms_parallel_execute.task_status(task_name => 'MyTask') = dbms_parallel_execute.FINISHED
```

and drop the task if it succeeded.

```
dbms_parallel_execute.drop_task(task_name => 'MyTask');
```

Answer (score 0):

Programs that spend a lot of time processing INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements, or looping through query results. You will want to investigate the FORALL statement for issuing DML, and the BULK COLLECT INTO and RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO clauses for queries.You can check this document out for your purpose.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/tuning.htm

And an answer here for your situiation.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330

Comment: While `bulk collect` and `forall` are valuable, it is usually better to perform batch updates.   Even if you can't update the whole table at once.